# Install Python and add to path automatically with just cmd

Tags: python, windows, python-install

Is there any way to download and install and add to path Python automatically with just one command or just series of commands with bat file?

I have tried with downloading and installing with following commands:

To download installer:

```
curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/python-3.7.9-amd64.exe -o python_install.exe
```

To install:

```
python_install.exe /passive InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0  Include_pip=1
```

But this does not add Python to path even after using `PrependPath=1`.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you try downloading Python from the official website by yourself?

1. Download the desired version of python from the Official Website https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Then open the file, you'll see an image like this,

   [image: Python Installation]
3. Just click the "Add Python 3.8 to PATH" (In my case)

And that will do it,

- Installed Python
- Added to PATH

Comment: That's not "with just cmd".